# Postman: How to attach file in Formdata with Content Disposition

Tags: rest, postman, multipartform-data, content-disposition, postman-testcase

I got following to run from postman

```
POST https://bonga.partner.com/api/v1/users/:user_id/image
Payload is multipart/form-data with name="image[file]"
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image[file]"; filename="FILENAME"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

In Postman i did following:
[image]

And in header i have following:
[image]

It returns 500 Error. Any idea what i am doing wrong?